Speed control for 2-wire BLDC motor
I found a question already asked (no answer)
BLDC speed control
If you are able to change speed when supplying different voltages to motor, why doesn't PWM work?
Here is a pump that I need to control with esp32 12V brushless pump

Motor in referenced question draws 0.29A (rated). Not going to get that from a GPIO directly.

If the pump is really brushless then an inverter is inside pumps case. There are many ways how this inverter can be implemented. The PC fans are Bldc and its speed varies with supply voltage regulation.
So in case of pump you posted all depends what control loop the designers used.
Another words, 50:50.
Regarding pwm, if you filter the pwm with LC there is no difference between varying voltage and changing duty of pwm.

Thank You. Considering what the pump costs, I think it is very possible that it is brushed. Had to google what LC filtering was. Will buy a couple and just test it.
